# how to get complete list of original fields along with new Fields which has been modified in trident?

Tags: apache-storm, trident

Suppose i have list of fields i.e, {field1,field2,field3,field4}
I performed some operation on field2 say i want to add increment each tuple values by some value say 5,

```
performed this operation in a function which gave me modified field with "M_field2" as out field name now i want to write complete tuple in a file but in place of field2 i want "M_field2". How i will achieve this.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue.. using trident just you have to use modified field name in list of input fields.
For example :-

```
topology.newStream("dummySpout",new DummySpout()).stateQuery(tridentState, new QueryFunctionClass(), new Fields("outLpi","outFileId"))
.each(new Fields("outLpi"),new DBReaderFunction((ArrayList<String>)conf.get("listOfFields")), new Fields((ArrayList<String>)conf.get("listOfFields")))
.each(new Fields((ArrayList<String>)conf.get("listOfFields")), new LoggerFilter())
.aggregate(new Fields("SAL"), new ApplyAggregator(),new Fields("sum"))
.each(new Fields("sum","SAL"),new LoggerFilter());
```

in last line "sum" is the  modified field and SAL is original field.

Answer (score 1):

From the [trident API page](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Trident-API-Overview) it says

> A function takes in a set of input fields and emits zero or more tuples as output. **The fields of the output tuple are appended to the original input tuple in the stream**. If a function emits no tuples, the original input tuple is filtered out. Otherwise, the input tuple is duplicated for each output tuple

Now digging more from the [trident tutorial page](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Trident-tutorial) found this
***With grouped streams, the output will contain the grouping fields followed by the fields emitted by the aggregator. For example:***

```
    stream.groupBy(new Fields("val1"))
     .aggregate(new Fields("val2"), new Sum(), new Fields("sum"))
```

In this example, the output will contain the fields `"val1" and "sum"`.

I am not sure but the closest one I can think of is doing something like

```
    stream.groupBy(new Fields("field1","field3","field4"))
     .aggregate(new Fields("field2"), new Sum(), new Fields("M_field2"))
```

might achieve what you are looking for. Correct me if I am wrong.